# Consequences of using a standard logit with heterogeneous preferences?

Tags: random-effects-model, logit

My understanding of the mixed logit is that it is designed to deal with situations where the population examined has heterogeneous preferences after taking into account all observed variables. The standard logit model on the other hand assumes homogeneous preferences given the observed information.

Standard logit $ u_{ijt} = \beta X_{ijt} + \epsilon_{ijt}$

Mixed logit $ u_{ijt} = \beta_{ijt} X_{ijt} + \epsilon_{ijt}$

Where $u_{ijt}$ indicates the utility that individual $i$ gets from making choice $j$ at time $t$.

My understanding from the literature, [Train 2009](http://eml.berkeley.edu/books/choice2nd/Ch06_p134-150.pdf), is that this allows for unrestricted substitution patterns and removes the independence of irrelevant  alternatives property.

What I would like to know is, what are the consequences if you estimate a standard logit model but the underlying data is one with heterogeneous preferences?